# how to fix miner address null PoA clique

Tags: javascript, ethereum, go-ethereum, genesis

Can anyone help my problem with unreadable miner aka null, I have modified the genesis.json file but miner is still null. is there something wrong with my genesis.json file or maybe some guide can help me?

[Image eth.getBlock(numberblock)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irFdV.png)

[Link File Genesis.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BCyXANYf0wJumikLGzwx5VgxXu6--qFY/view?usp=sharing)

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior with clique (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-225#specification). If you somehow need to identify the signer, you need to decode the extra data. If you still somehow want the signer address to be present, you can switch to AuRA PoA consensus (OpenEthereum/Nethermind) which will include it in the block miner/signer field.